# object reference in javascript/angular directive variable

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular directive that takes in an object, and I will need to reassign that the object and i cant do it

```
<span search-drop-down selected-object="selectedObjectVar"></span>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedObjectVar = {Name: "Bob"};
});

myApp.directive('searchDropDown', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            selectedObject: '='
        },

        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.selectedObject = {Name: "Sam"};
        }
};
```

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3170/

this works only if you change the ng-show to ng-if ... i need to use ng-if in this case. Anyone shed some light on this??

Comment: The `selected-object` attribute should be in kebab-case not camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
scope: {selectedObject: '=selectedObject',},
```

Answer (score 0):

While you do `$scope.B = $scope.A;` runtime refers to same object for `a` and `b` both. but then when you do `$scope.B = {Name: "BBB"};` var B is assigned new reference which is problem with you.

Instead assign the property only like

```
$scope.B.Name = "BBB";
```

that will cause Name property of A as well to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$scope.digest();` after assignment

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $scope.selectedObject = null;
    $scope.selectedObject = { Name: "AAA" };
    $scope.digest();
}
```